# Connection Error in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, connection, database-connection

Ohk, I just started to learn PHP and MySQL. Everything was going fine untill this thing boiled up my mind.
Here is the problem.
I have two php files in the same directory.

**mysql.php--->**

```
<?php
require("connect.php")or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

**connect.php--->**

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$connect=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("phpacademy")or die(mysql_error());
echo"Connected!";
?>
```

The problem is that whenever I am running the connect.php script directly, its working fine.
But when I run mysql.php to connect to the other script it gives the following error:

Warning: require(1): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\stckovrflw1\mysql.php on line 3

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '1' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\stckovrflw1\mysql.php on line 3

Its not getting the file even though it exists and the spelling is obviously not incorrect.
And the most amazing part is that, as soon as I remove the or die() everything works like a charm.
As I am a beginner I have no idea whats going on. I supposed that or die() is just for developer's or user's help to see the exact error, but in this case it is causing the error itself.

Do help!!!

Thanks in advance...:)

P.S.: I am running on localhost as mentioned in code also.

Comment: just before your `require` line, add `echo getcwd();` so you can see in what directory you ar at that moment. Possibly the path to connect.php is wrong.

Comment: well checked the directory.
Its correct!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**or** has a higher precedence than **require/require_once**. Therefore php evaluates

```
('connect.php') or die("blah blah")
```

before passing the result to require. `Or` takes two boolean operands. ('connect.php') evaluates to `true` therefore the whole expression is true and

`require true;`

is invoked.

`require` takes string as parameter, so true casts to 1 by php.

so it became `require 1` in your case

that generate `failed to open error`

A bug reported on bugs.php.net https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=15438 says:

> "Because include() is a special language costruct, parentheses are not
>   needed around its argument. Take care when comparing return value.

```
<?php
// won't work, evaluated as include(('vars.php') == 'OK'), i.e. include('')
if (include('vars.php') == 'OK') {
    echo 'OK';
}

// works
if ((include 'vars.php') == 'OK') {
    echo 'OK';
}
```

Comment: Wow!!!
Thanks for the reply.
I got to know many new things.
And solved the problem by just replacing that line by this:
(require("connect.php"))or die(mysql_error());

Answer (score 1):

It is **mysql_select_db**  and not mysql_selectdb

and by the way if you have begun learning php and mysql, better get yourself trained using **mysqli** and not mysql

You don't have to use die() in the **require** line, if the file is not present PHP will automatically throw error

FYI:

die() method comes in handy for debugging yes!! thts true when you want to stop the execution of some loop or code flow when you want to analyse what are the variables that you get as output and the ones that you dont

Comment: thnaks for your reply.
I corrected the _db code and thanks for enhancing my knowledge...:)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
require("connect.php")or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

Does not work. PHP at first evaluates the expression

```
("connect.php") or die(mysql_error())
```

And this expression is always true. The result ist:

```
require true
```

This doesn't work. You even don't need to check the connection because you checked this in your `connect.php`. But double checking is not wrong and it's better for future compatibility (for example you can change your implementation and remove the check in connect.php). So you can use this instead:

```
<?php
require("connect.php");

if(!$connect)
    die(mysql_error());
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

error_reporting(0);

$connect=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());

mysql_selectdb("phpacademy",$connect)or die(mysql_error());

echo"Connected!";

Answer (score 0):

You need to set you PHP.INI
It is clear that your include path is set to default, which is (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR')

You PHP-config is looking for file in 'C:\xampp\php\PEAR', which is not there.
Try set_include_path() (reference: www.php.net/set_include_path)

```
<?php
set_include_path('C:\xampp\htdocs\stckovrflw1\');
require("connect.php")or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

mysql_selectdb("phpacademy",$connect)or die(mysql_error());